# Turn off indexing in hibernate search

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

I have hibernate search set-up and it's (re-)indexing my annotated entities up on commit just fine.

But I have a number of integration tests which have only partially initilzed data. Since this is throwing exceptions when hibernate search tries to index this objects, I'd prefer to completely switch off the indexing (or hibernate search) for this tests.

I already tried to not set `hibernate.search.default.indexBase` and `hibernate.search.default.directory_provider` for the tests. But this didn't help.

How can I switch off hibernate search indexing?

Comment: have you set the `hibernate.search.indexing_strategy` to manual?

Comment: That does the trick. Thanks! Feal free to add your comment as answer to get the credits.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

set the `hibernate.search.indexing_strategy` configuration property to `manual`

for further reference, feel free to check the documentation [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.3/reference/en-US/html_single/#_automatic_indexing).

Answer (score 5):

if you want to disable all hibernate search feature (for instance for a dev environment), you need to set these 2 options :

```
hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners = false
hibernate.search.indexing_strategy = manual
```

the second one only disable the "write" operations on indexes not "read"